# Dial number from web page

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I want to dial number using javascript.

I have used following code 
document.location.href = "tel:15555551212"

It brings me to dial screen of mobile application. But I want to make a call directly.

I have also used "callto" but it is not working.

Comment: yup, you need an OS-level permission to directly dial a number. Not going to get that within the browser.

Comment: You don't even get to do that from phone book by tapping the name: you have to specifically tap the "phone" icon. You are looking to implement a "nuisance" feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, unless:

- the Web browser holds the `CALL_PHONE` permission (so that the user knows at install time that this app might place phone calls), and
- the Web browser exposes some means to have you place a phone call directly, perhaps via some DOM extension or magic snippet of JavaScript

Few, if any, browsers will meet these criteria.

A hybrid application (e.g., PhoneGap) could do this, given the proper permission and some API to enable it (e.g., PhoneGap plugin, if it is not part of the standard PhoneGap API).

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use apache cordova to get access to native device APIs, including the one you can dial with. [Link to the respective plugin](https://github.com/anemitoff/PhoneGap-PhoneDialer)

This is obviosuly only possible on mobile devices, and this plugin can only operate on iOS and Android. For more information about cordova, see [this Link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview).